# iOS app detection from OS X APP

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ipad

I have created an OS X application which is supposed to interact with iOS devices(iPhone/iPad) for some functional use and the iOS device is USB connected to OS X machine.
So I want to know how can I check whether a particular APP is installed or not on iOS devices(iPhone/iPad) from my OS X APP programmatically?
Also how to get iOS devices details in OS X APP.

Comment: almost certain you can't do it via USB. Bluetooth could work. or use a shared WiFi network + Bonjour

Comment: @nielsbot can't we detect over USB connection? My OS X APP requires details of attached iOS devices(iPhone/iPad). How does iTunes get all this details? We cannot do the similar way?

Comment: like I said you cannot communicate via USB and you won't be able to do what iTunes does.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has provided no public API for an OS X app to communicate with an iOS device over USB.  The best you can do is [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html).  However you cannot do what Xcode and iTunes do.

Comment: I have found one link https://github.com/xslim/mobileDeviceManager but this code gives information of only one device and it fails for multiple devices. So how can I achieve it?Any help appreciated.

Comment: This isn't something that Apple is going to let you do easily.  It would be a big security issue for them.  Even the MDM systems only get to modify some plists and documents, and not scan your iPhone.  This is as far as I can tell.